# Remove-RoleMember - Sitecore Powershell extensions

Tags: sitecore, powershell-4.0

How does the command Remove-RoleMember works ?

I tried using
Remove-RoleMember -Identity "developer" -Member "XYZ"

(sitecore\XYZ role is added as member of sitecore\developer role with the Add-RoleMember command, which worked correctly)

There are no errors when I executed this command. However, the role is not removed from the Developer role. The command works if you pass a sitecore user as an argument in the -Member argument.

I have Sitecore 8.1 and v4.0 Powershell extensions installed. Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with : Remove-RoleMember -Identity developer -Members "XYZ"

Looks like you wrote **"developer"** and not **developer**  and you wrote **-Member** and not **-Members**

Please also check description of this command [here](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Remove-RoleMember.html)

Comment: I tried this approach already. It didn't remove the role member.

Comment: I tried locally and is working fine. Check your role name, your user domain